# app crashing on login button pressed in emulator-(android studio)

Tags: android

My app crashes when the login button is pressed

When the login button is pressed an alert dialog box should appear, and then switch to next activity.

It works fine when the 'getText.to string' statements are removed

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText id_txt,password_txt;

    ImageButton lgin;
    private AlphaAnimation signupclick = new AlphaAnimation(1F, 0.1F);
    private AlphaAnimation loginclick = new AlphaAnimation(1F, 0.5F);


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setRequestedOrientation (ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        id_txt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.id) ;
        password_txt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.pass);

        onClickButtonListner();
    }

    public void onClickButtonListner() {
        lgin = (ImageButton).findViewById(R.id.login_btn);
        lgin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                v.startAnimation(loginclick);
                String id_string = id_txt.getText().toString();
                String password_string = password_txt.getText().toString();
                String type = "login";
                Intent intent = new Intent(com.example.cortana.shope2.MainActivity.this,com.example.cortana.shope2.search.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker(this);
                backgroundWorker.execute(type,id_string,password_string);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The `BackgroundWorker` is another class

This is the trace log from clicking on the login button

> java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.cortana.shope2.MainActivity$1 cannot be cast to android.content.Context
>       at com.example.cortana.shope2.BackgroundWorker.(BackgroundWorker.java:30)
>       at com.example.cortana.shope2.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:52)
>       at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
>       at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966) 
>       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
>       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786) 
>       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
>       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: Please paste your trace log.

Answer (score 0):

If your BackgroundWorker class needs Context in its constructor then you should write this

```
BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker(MainActivity.this);
```

Comment: still app crashes

Answer (score 0):

The crash is casued by this line : `BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker(this);`

Change it to

```
BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker(MainActivity.this);
```

It's trying to use the button as its context

Change it to this?

```
BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker(com.example.cortana.shope2.MainActivity.this);
```

Comment: Error:(51, 111) error: incompatible types: MainActivity cannot be converted to OnClickListener

Comment: @arunberlin Chekc my edit, Change `new BackgroundWorker(MainActivity.this);` to this `new BackgroundWorker(com.example.cortana.shope2.MainActivity.this);`

Answer (score 0):

You must edit the BackgroundWorker class and the MainActivity must implement OnClickListener. The edited code will be

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

EditText id_txt,password_txt;

ImageButton lgin;
private AlphaAnimation signupclick = new AlphaAnimation(1F, 0.1F);
private AlphaAnimation loginclick = new AlphaAnimation(1F, 0.5F);


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
setRequestedOrientation (ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

id_txt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.id) ;
password_txt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.pass);

onClickButtonListner();

}

public void onClickButtonListner()
{

lgin = (ImageButton).findViewById(R.id.login_btn);
lgin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
                         {
                             @Override
                             public void onClick(View v)
                             {
                                 v.startAnimation(loginclick);
                                 String id_string = id_txt.getText().toString();
                                 String password_string = password_txt.getText().toString();
                                 String type = "login";
                                 Intent intent = new Intent(com.example.cortana.shope2.MainActivity.this,com.example.cortana.shope2.search.class);
                                 startActivity(intent);
                                 BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker(MainActivity.this);
                                 backgroundWorker.execute(type,id_string,password_string);

                             }
                         }
);
}
}
```

If there are multiple `MainActivity` in the project, then add `com.example.cortana.shope2` before MainActivity.